# $.mobile.changePage not changing page?

Tags: jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile

here is HTML code:

```
 <div data-role="page" id="mainMenu">
    <div data-role="header">

    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
    <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true"
                                        style="margin-top:50%; margin-left:20%;">
     <li id="prayerId" data-theme="b"><a href="#"><img
                                                src="css/images/namazimage.jpg" />PRAYERS </a>
                                        </li>
     <li id="goalId" data-theme="e"><a href="#"><img
                                                src="css/images/namazimage.jpg" />GOAL </a>
                                        </li>

     </ul>
     </div>
    </div>
    <!-- //////////////////////// PRAYER PAGE START //////////////////////////////////////  --> 
        <div data-role="page" id="prayer">
            <div data-role="header" data-theme="b"></div>
            <div data-role="content"></div>
            <div data-role="footer" data-theme="e" data-position="fixed">

                <div data-role="navbar">

                    <ul>
                        <li id="namazId"><a href="#" data-role="tab" data-icon="grid">NAMAZ</a></li>
                        <li id="fastId"><a href="#" data-role="tab" data-icon="grid">FAST</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

<!-- //////////////////////// PRAYER PAGE END //////////////////////////////////////  -->
```

this s the code which is written in separate js file:

```
$('#mainMenu').live('pageinit', function() {
    $('#prayerId').off('click').on('click', function() {
        alert("prayer id");
        $.mobile.changePage("#prayer", null, true, true);
        //$.mobile.changePage('#loginPage', null, true, true);

    });
});
$('#prayer').live('pageinit',function()
 {  
    alert("prayer page");
    $('#namazId').off('click').on('click', function() {
        alert("namaz page");
        //$.mobile.changePage('#mainMenu', null, true, true);
        $.mobile.changePage('#namazPage', null, true, true);

    });
});
```

but over here change page is not working all references of jquery and cordova is already added using cordova 2.0.0 and jquery 1.7.1

Comment: Try `$.mobile.changePage('#namazPage')` without null, true, true.

Comment: @omar  still no any changes

Comment: @user1668447 check your tags. Generally `changePage` fails to work when there's an unclosed tag, or an extra tag.

Comment: all tags are fine its working some time and sometimes failed to work

Comment: Why are wrapping it with `pageinit`? it fires once and its useless to bind `click` event to `pageinit`. It can work separately. Check this http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/wre7k/

Comment: i think there is a problem of pageinit

Answer (score 1):

Remove `click` events out of [`pageinit`](http://api.jquerymobile.com/pageinit/) event. [`pageinit`](http://api.jquerymobile.com/pageinit/) fires once only on page initialization, afterwards, any event attached to it will be neglected.

```
$('#prayerId').off('click').on('click', function () {
 alert("prayer id");
 $.mobile.changePage("#prayer", null, true, true);
});

$('#namazId').off('click').on('click', function () {
 alert("namaz page");
 $.mobile.changePage('#namazPage', null, true, true);
});
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/wre7k/)**

Comment: but i dnt want to write this code in my script tag because so many people aer working in a project thats why to avoid conflict want to put my code in my separate js  file named as namaz.js  how can i write my code there pls explain

Comment: you can do it this way `$(document).on('click', '#prayerId', function ()` or `$('a').on('click', '#prayerId', function ()` or `$(document).on('click', 'a#prayerId', function ()`. It can be written in many ways. you can also replace `document` with `'#pageID'`. Keeping in mind that each element should have a unique `id` and not to be used twice. @user1668447

Comment: @user1668447 No I haven't :) if you need help just post a question.

Comment: here is my jqplot question   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16217392/jqplot-not-working-for-dynamic-data

Comment: @user1668447 sorry, I'm not jqplot expert :)