# jqplot not working for dynamic data

Tags: jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile, jqplot, jquery-mobile-pageshow

I am trying to use **jqplot** to plot bar chart graph of data retrieving from SQLite DB for Phonegap - Android how to use the same code for db values. this code with static data is working fine inside of  tag but when i m trying to put this code inside of `$('#pageid').live('pageinit',function(){});` then its not working. what's the reason?

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/lib/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/lib/jquery.jqplot.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/lib/jqplot.barRenderer.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/lib/jqplot.categoryAxisRenderer.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/lib/jqplot.pointLabels.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/lib/jquery.jqplot.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
 var s1 = [10,0,0,0,0];
 var s2 = [0,20,0,0,0];
 var s3 = [0,0,30,0,0];
 var s4 = [0,0,0,25,0];
 var s5 = [0,0,0,0,0];
 var ticks = ['FAJR', 'ZOHAR', 'ASR', 'MAGHRIB','ISHA'];    

 var plot1 = $.jqplot('chart1', [s1, s2, s3,s4,s5], {
        // The "seriesDefaults" option is an options object that will
        // be applied to all series in the chart.
        seriesDefaults:{
             title:'Namaz Vs MissingPrayer',
            renderer:$.jqplot.BarRenderer,
            rendererOptions: {fillToZero: true}
        },
        series:[
                {label:'Fajr'},
                {label:'Z'},
                {label:'A'},
                {label:'M'},
                {label:'I'}


            ],
            legend: {
                show: true,
                placement: 'outsideGrid'
            },
            axes: {
                // Use a category axis on the x axis and use our custom ticks.
                xaxis: {
                    renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,
                    label:'NAMAZ',
                    ticks: ticks,

                },
                // Pad the y axis just a little so bars can get close to, but
                // not touch, the grid boundaries.  1.2 is the default padding.
                yaxis: {
                    min:0,
                    label:'MISSING PRAYERS',
                    pad: 1.05,
                    tickOptions: {formatString: '%d'}
                }
            }
        });
});
 </script>
</head>
<body>
<div data-role="page" id="graph">
<div data-role="content">
<div id="chart1" style="width:600px; height:350px;"></div>
</div>
</div>
</body>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to put it inside a **[pageshow](http://api.jquerymobile.com/pageshow/)** event.

Page height can be calculated correctly only during the **[pageshow](http://api.jquerymobile.com/pageshow/)** event.

So use it like this:

```
$(document).on('pageshow','#pageid',function(){});
```

Also if you are using jQuery version 1.9.1+ then you can't use **[live](http://api.jquery.com/live/)** because it was deprecated and it no longer exist.

Comment: yes its working fine with http://api.jquerymobile.com/pageshow/ but pls let me know how can i update graph by clicking on update or refresh button

Comment: how to refresh jqplot bar chart after retrieving data from SQLITE-DB

Comment: even have applied $('chart1').empty(); but still no effect

Comment: can u describe me howto use replot i m using it but its not working and every time i m getting garbage values in graph

Comment: pls give the answer if possible:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16417660/phonegap-android-localnotification-plugin-display-nothing