# phonegap android localnotification plugin display nothing

Tags: cordova, localnotification

I have followed this: [localnotification android phonegap for cordova 2.x+](https://github.com/conrad10781/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/LocalNotification) 
getting nothing in device: here is some results of  my console.log:

```
05-07 21:04:20.218: E/dalvikvm(21039): threadid=5: stuck on threadid=12, giving up
05-07 21:04:20.218: D/dalvikvm(21039): threadid=5: sending two SIGSTKFLTs to threadid=12 (tid=21062) to cause debuggerd dump
05-07 21:04:22.218: D/dalvikvm(21039): Sent, pausing to let debuggerd run
05-07 21:04:22.867: A/libc(21039): Fatal signal 16 (SIGSTKFLT) at 0x0000522f (code=-6)
```

Here is the code of html page and every thing follow from the above mentioned link

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
document.addEventListener("deviceready",appReady, false);
function appReady() {
     window.plugins = {
             LocalNotificationPlugin: cordova.require( 'cordova/plugin/localNotification' )
         };
    console.log("Device ready");
    alert("");

    var now = new Date();
    now.setSeconds(now.getSeconds() + 90);  
    window.plugins.LocalNotificationPlugin.add({
        date :now,
        message : "Phonegap - Local Notification\r\nSubtitle comes after linebreak",
        ticker : "This is a sample ticker text",
        repeatDaily : false,
        id : 4
});
}
</script
```

Comment: Can you show us your codes as well ?

Comment: have mentioned the code

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17198707/local-notification-repeated-every-day-in-phonegap-android. Let me know if it doesn't help

Answer (score 0):

Check out https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-plugin-localNotifications

It is regularly maintained and is used in production games by Wizcorp.